# Insert multiple rows in sqlite using content values

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am returning multiple rows from `mysql` with `JSON` , but only one row is being accepted to `sqlite` , how can i insert all of it :

MainActivity.java :

```
            .....
        if (!error) {

                        // user successfully exist in database
                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                        String id = user.getString("id");
                        String sutdentId = user.getString("sutdentId");
                        String full_name = user.getString("full_name");
                        String year = user.getString("year");
                        String school = user.getString("school");
                        String level = user.getString("level");

                        // pass id ,fullname ,year ,school and level to 
        sqlite
                       db.addUser(id, sutdentId, full_name, year, school, 
 level);

      .....
```

`SqliteHandle.java` which is used to hold method of inserting and table creation:

```
     public void addUser( String id, String sutdentId, String full_name 
   ,String 
      year, String school, String level) {
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_userId, id);
    values.put(KEY_Student, sutdentId);
    values.put(KEY_Names, full_name);
    values.put(KEY_Year, year);
    values.put(KEY_School, school);
    values.put(KEY_Level, level);
long Id = db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
        Log.d(TAG, "New user inserted into sqlite: " + Id);
        if (Id > 0 ) {
            Log.d(TAG, "New user inserted into database: " + Id);
        }
        else{
            Log.d(TAG, "OOps! No data inserted in mysql ");
        }
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
```

Comment: it's a bit hard to tell given that the code formatting is all off, but it seems you're calling the insert function only once

Comment: Where you are looping through your multiple result dataset from MySQL?  In MainActivity.java -- all I see is a single call to your addUser function.

Comment: @ QuickNull , yes is a single call  is a reason why i need to know how i can loop it

Comment: @gramandagrandish it depends a bit what you get from the mysql, in your code we only see one "user" object, which only holds one user. You should probably receive an array with multiple users, so if you can provide how the input looks like we can give some more detailed help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over your `jsonArray` to insert all rows.
You can use a compiled statement to make the execution much faster.

The code will look roughly like this:

```
//a field that holds the compiled statement
private SQLiteStatement insStmt = null;

//assuming you have "JSONArray users" loaded;
for (int i = 0 ; i < users.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj = users.getJSONObject(i);
    String id = obj.getString("id");
    String studentId = obj.getString("studentId");
    String full_name = obj.getString("full_name");
    String year = obj.getString("year");
    String school = obj.getString("school");
    String level = obj.getString("level");
    addUser(id, sutdentId, full_name, year, school, level);
}
```

Now the addUser function will look like this (with compiled statement).

```
function addUser(String id, String sutdentId, String full_name 
   ,String year, String school, String level) {

    if (insStmt == null) { //compile it once
        String query = "INSERT into "+TABLE_NAME+"(id, studentId, full_name, year, school, level) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        insStmt = myDataBase.compileStatement(query);
    }

    //bind the arguments
    insStmt.bindAllArgsAsStrings(String[]{id, studentId, full_name, year, school, level});
    //execute
    insStmt.execute();
}
```

Comment: this array `String[]` is showing an error. but about loop the `jsonArray ` was already loop ,the problem was that i didn't include it in the post

Comment: I get `SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed` because `studentId ` is unique, and i need to skip this existing row and insert unexisting ones

Comment: Than make the query `INSERT or IGNORE`